# How to write the post method in ionic?

Tags: ionic2

I am new to the ionic framework,I had written the post call, I don't know exactly the post method.When i entered the submit button in forgot password page,if the user is already registered then should display the next page else it should display the alert message.
Below is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { configurator } from  '../../providers/configurator';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
 // import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
 import { persistence } from '../persistence/persistence';

   @Component({
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
   })
   export class home {

  public loginId = "";

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }
     generateOTP(newstate) {
     console.log("invoking generateOTP FN");
     var _this = this;
     this.login.generateOTP(this.loginId, function(result,data){
     if(result == '1') {
     alert(data);
     var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.href="OTP page";
     }
   else {
    //this.showRePasswd = this.showRePasswd;
    alert(data);
       }
     })
    }
   }
```

This is my ionic-page:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGRda.png)
 Can anyone help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

my post belowed in IONIC2

```
 import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http) { }

 this.http.post(`${POST_URL}/log/add`, JSON.stringify(this.currentLocation), {headers})
        .toPromise() 
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status !== 201) {
                this.trace.error('log','postLog',`error response: ${response.status}`);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.trace.error('log','postLog',`err post log:${error}`);
        });
```